# Supabase realtime subscriptions times out

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, supabase, supabase-database

Im trying to listen to realtime changes in my react-native app from a supabase table called "profiles". Whatever i try, i can't get it to subscribe to change son the table. Even when copying the code snippet from the generated docs in Supabase:

```js
const profiles = supabase.channel('custom-all-channel')
  .on(
    'postgres_changes',
    { event: '*', schema: 'public', table: 'profiles' },
    (payload) => {
      console.log('Change received!', payload)
    }
  )
  .subscribe()
```

Nothing happens when updating the table. When i pass a callback function to the subscribe method, it listens to events trigger on the subscription:

```js
const profiles = supabase.channel('custom-all-channel')
  .on(
    'postgres_changes',
    { event: '*', schema: 'public', table: 'profiles' },
    (payload) => {
      console.log('Change received!', payload)
    }
  )
  .subscribe((event) => {
    console.log(event)
  })
```

However, the only event to trigger is the `TIMED_OUT` event.

I have enabled realtime changes to the "profiles" table in Supabase".

I've also tried changing the timeout to a longer amount of time, still doesn't work.

All other things like auth and normal fetching from the DB works fine.

I'm not using the local supabase Docker image for developing.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Can you please email support@supabase.com so the team can take a look?

Comment: @thorwebdev was a solution reached for this issue? I am also facing the same issue. Would it be possible to share the solution here?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue, on Firefox. The realtime subscription worked for a day, then stopped working and started throwing TIMED_OUTs.

After quadruple checking everything else, including recreating the supabase installation, nothing helped.

Turns out the solution was to restart Firefox. No idea why, maybe they mess up their socket cleanup when refreshing a page, and reach a limit.

Comment: I had fresh instances of Chrome/Firefox where these would occasionally happen.

Comment: Same for me. Happened just now and closing chrome resolved.